# Burnside’s Lemma for a triangle (group action clarification)

Tags: group-theory, permutations, orbit-stabilizer

This is a follow up to the answer to this question: [Using Burnside's lemma for a triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3187381/using-burnsides-lemma-for-a-triangle)

I am confused about this because $D3$ is the set of symmetries of the triangle $D_3=S_3=\{g:V=\{1,2,3 \} \rightarrow V \mid g \text{ is bijective}\}$ i.e. permutations of $V$. $X$ is the set of colorings, $X=\{x: V \rightarrow \{R,B,Y,G\}\}$, say for four colors.

The notation the answerer used, g.x, implies a permutation in $D3$ acts on the coloring of the vertices. However, $g(x(v))$ for $x$ in $X$, is not a valid composition since g’s domain isn’t $\{R, G, Y, B\}$.Wouldn’t it be more accurate to talk about the action of $x$ on $g$?

Comment: Sorry I wasn’t sure if anyone would see my question on there

Comment: The Dihedral group $D_3$ has order $6$; it is usually described as the group of rigid motions of a triangle. It is not the group of all permutations of a set of $4$ elements (which has $24$ elements).

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant D4, I was doing a square in my example, but my question still applies

Comment: The group acts on the  triangle. That means that it acts on the set of possible ways to color the triangle. It doesn't act on the colors, it acts on the triangle, or it acts on the set of **painted triangles**.

Comment: You are still wrong; the group is acting on the square, not on the colors. So it can be seen as acting on a set of painted squares, by sending a painted square to a painted square. It is not a permutation of the colors themselves, but of the painted squares.

Comment: So, you meant $D_4$, you are talking about a square, but your subject line says "triangle", your post links to a problem about triangles, and you never mention any shape other than triangles. Are we supposed to read your mind?

Comment: I fixed my post

Comment: But didn't listen. The group does not act on the set of colors. It acts on the set of painted triangles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140954/discussion-between-elbecker-and-arturo-magidin).

Comment: I don't do chat. Your problem is that you are inventing notation that is not in the original post. The correct expression is not $g(x(v))$, it is $(g\cdot x)(v)$. And it's not the vertices that are colored, it's the edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused about the action. The group $G$ is not acting on the set of colors, it is acting on the set of colored triangles. In the problem you linked to, it is the edges that are colored, using four possible colors (not the vertices).

Imagine a triangle on the plane, with vertices at $(1,0)$, $(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1}{2})$, and $(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},-\frac{1}{2})$, in that order.

Denote a coloring by listing three colors in a given order, with the first color corresponding to the edge from $(1,0)$ to the vertex in the second quadrant, the second color corresponding to the edge going from the second to the third quadrant, and the third color corresponding to the edge going from the third quadrant to $(1,0)$. Label the colors $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$. So a coloring is a three digit number all of whose digits are between $1$ and $4$.

Denote $D_3$, as usual, by $D_3=\{e, r, r^2, s, rs, r^2s\}$, where $e$ is the identity rigid motion, $r$ is a counterclockwise rotation by $120$ degrees, $r^2$ is a counterclockwise rotation by $240$ degrees, $s$ is the reflection about the $x$-axis, $rs$ is the reflection followed by the rotation $r$, and $r^2s$ is the reflection followied by the rotation $r^2$.

The group $D_3$ does not act on the colors, it acts on the full colorings. The set of colorings consists of $4^3 = 64$ colored triangles:
$$111, 112, 113, 114, 121, 122, 123, 124, 131,\ldots, 441, 442, 443, 444.$$

Let $C$ be the set of colorings. Then $D_3$ acts on $C$ by taking a colored triangle, applying to it an element of $D_3$, and obtaining a colored triangle. For example, if you take the colored triangle $123$, then
$$\begin{align*}
e\cdot 123 &= 123\\
r\cdot 123 &= 312\\
r^2\cdot 123 &= 231\\
s\cdot 123 &= 321\\
rs\cdot 123 &= 132\\
r^2s\cdot 123&=213
\end{align*}$$
We can then see that the orbit of the coloring $123$ is precisely the colorings $\{123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321\}$.

You can instead think of the colorings as maps $c\colon\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}\to \{1,2,3,4\}$, where $c(e_i)$ is the color of the $i$th edge. To describe a coloring, then, I need to tell you its value at each of $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$.

So if $c$ is a coloring, and $g\in D_3$, then to describe $g\cdot c$ I can tell you the value of $g\cdot c$ at each of $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$. So what you want is to describe wht $(g\cdot c)(e_1)$, $(g\cdot c)(e_2)$, and $(g\cdot c)(e_3)$ are.

You are mistakenly writing these expressions as $g(c(e_1))$, $g(c(e_2))$, and $g(c(e_2))$. You are correct that those expressions are nonsensical... but those expressions are not in the original post, they are in your incorrect paraphrase of what is written in that post.